# installation package "tm" fails

Tags: r, installation, tm

I am trying to install package "tm" and get an error (see below). From this error I can't see what is going wrong. Package Rcpp is installed. Working on R 3.4.0, Xubuntu 64.

How can I install package tm?

```
* installing *source* package ‘tm’ ...
** package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BH/include" -I"/home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from /home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:34:0,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/grow.h:73:47: fatal error: Rcpp/generated/grow__pairlist.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: recipe for target 'RcppExports.o' failed
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tm’
* removing ‘/home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'tm' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmp3tKSat/downloaded_packages'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    At first we can install "devtools" packages and than install "tm" 
    by using devtools::install_cran("tm")
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tm' in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database '/home/henk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb' is corrupt`

Comment: Saw [this](https://github.com/wch/movies/issues/3) comment on Github; restarted R and did `devtools::install_cran("tm", force = T)` and this time it installed.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp
```

Comment: Tried that already. As said in the question, library Rcpp is installed.